# Incorrect phone number on my Craigslist account

Tags: craigslist

Somehow my phone number used on Craigslist has been changed so when I post something for sale, the responder clicks reply and gets an incorrect phone number and thus I don't get any calls.

How can I get Craigslist to correct my phone number?

Answer (score 1):

The phone number appears to be linked to the listing rather than to your user account.

You'll need to edit your listing(s) to fix that.

[Craigslist help: Editing](http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/free-edit)